# Elegant way to switch off logging F#

Tags: logging, functional-programming, f#

In my F# code I have a lot of logging. Something like this

```
logger.Log (sprintf "%A" (this.GetSomething parameters))
```

It all works well but the performance is low even with NullLogger due to a lot of sprintf calls. The string parameter for the log call is fully formed and then beign ignored at the end inside Log function

Is there a good way to completely switch off logging? Of course I could do preprocessor directives (are there such thing in F#?) or somehow use 'if flag then ....' but I am wondering if there is a F# magic which would do it nicely for me?

Comment: The usual approach is to make the `Log` method itself take the format string and all the parameters.

Comment: this will not help with heavy call of this.GetSomething function

Comment: Then wrap it in a lambda

Comment: Just go with structured logging instead of building strings. For rare cases when you call some functions instead of logging value you can manually check if logger is enabled for the required log level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this by using the `Conditional("SYMBOL")` attribute. The `Log` method may or may not already have this (as this is a standard .NET attribute). If you apply `Conditional` attribute on a method, the compiler will only compile the call when the attribute is specified - so you can use `Conditional("DEBUG")` to completely remove the call unless you compile with `--define:DEBUG`. Most importantly, this also removes all the code computing the argument. For example:

```
type Logger() = 
  [<System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")>]
  member x.Log(s:string) = printfn "%s" s

let slowprintf f =
  Printf.kprintf (fun k -> printfn "SLOWPRINTF!"; k) f

let l = Logger()
l.Log(slowprintf "Yo %d" (System.Random().Next()))
```

If you compile this with `--define:DEBUG`, it prints `SLOWPRINTF!` (when formatting) and then `Yo xyz` with some random number (when logging). But without `--define:DEBUG` it does not print anything - not even the message from `slowprintf`.

Comment: A word of warning: the `ConditionalAttribute` only works correctly on members that have non-curried arguments and that are not used as first-class functions. However, you can consider making `sprintf`-style overloads in tuple-style arguments where the first argument is the `sprintf`-string: if done right, in-string coloring of arguments will remain. This is how I do it in my own logging framework. See also this discussion and language suggestion: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/846.